# ADO.Net Insert strongly-typed Row without loading dataset to memory

Tags: c#, ado.net

Is there a way to insert a row using ADO.Net without filling the dataset or specifying the columns?  My datasets may be large, so I don't want to load them just to add a row.  I know I can insert using an adapter and specifying the columns, but I'll need to do this for many tables so I don't want to create custom code for handling each different table.

Comment: What do you mean, without specifying the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load your table into an ADO.NET DataSet using a query like this:

```
select * from myTable where (1=0)
```

This will give you a zero-row dataset.

Then add your row to the dataset and get the adapter to save it for you.